# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'

Tags: android, macos, gradle, flutter, dart

Я склонировал репозиторий проекта на flutter, запускаю приложение на эмуляторе андроида и получаю следующий лог

```
    Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for arm64 in debug mode...
[flutter_background_geolocation] Purging debug resources in release build
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     /Users/arthur/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/5df5e982d3c927d859e132fe495f1ced/appauth-0.10.0/AndroidManifest.xml:24:5-32:15: AAPT: error: unexpected element <queries> found in <manifest>.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 12s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

Переустанавливал Android Studio, обновлял gradle через homebrew, делал flutter clean - ничего не помогает.

Comment: Если репозиторий открытый, дайте ссылку. На реальном андроиде проблема воспроизводится?

Comment: репозиторий закрытый, на реальном не тестил. Пробовал еще либу затестить, тоже склонировал и там похожая проблема, тоже ссылается на gradle: https://github.com/bazrafkan/google_place

Comment: Попробуйте удалить `gradle` из `homebrew` и пусть Android Studio сама последнюю версию установит. И дайте ссылку на какой-то открытый репозиторий, где проблема наблюдается.

Comment: удалял, не помогает, к сожалению

Comment: удалите папку `android` из проекта и выполните `flutter create .`.